# I can't get results to echo in a separate part of the file

Tags: php

I want to echo the results in a different part of the page and not just in the header. How do I do this? What if I want to 6 items to be echoed separately?

```
<?php 

    require_once 'facebook.php';
    $appapikey = 'CENSORED';
    $appsecret = 'CENSORED';
    $facebook  = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
    $user_id  = $facebook->require_login();
    $user   = $user_id;
    $i = 0;
     $fql = 'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$user.')';
     $_friends = $facebook->api_client->fql_query($fql); // Extract the user ID's returned in the FQL request into a new array. 
     $friends = array(); 
     if (is_array($_friends) && count($_friends)) 
     {
      foreach ($_friends as $friend) 
      { 
       $i++;
       $friends[] = $friend['uid'];
       if ($i<=6) echo $friend['uid']."@[,:m]";
      } 
     }
    ?>


    <br><br>HELLO
```

Comment: It's a bit late for this, but, anyone could now use your facebook app. I recommend you reset your application secret right now. Really, go, now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `echo` then. Collect all the output in the string variable and `echo` it when it really needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well if it's on the same page you could just access the $_friends variable wherever you wanted to on the page.

```
require_once 'facebook.php';
$appapikey = <KEY>;
$appsecret = <SECRET>;
$facebook  = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user_id  = $facebook->require_login();
$user   = $user_id;
$i = 0;
 $fql = 'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$user.')';
 $_friends = $facebook->api_client->fql_query($fql); // Extract the user ID's returned in the FQL request into a new array. 
 $friends = array(); 
 if (is_array($_friends) && count($_friends)) 
 {
  foreach ($_friends as $friend) 
  { 
   $i++;
   if ($i<=6) $friends[] = $friend['uid']."@[,:m]";
  } 
 }
?>

 BUNCH OF STUFF

<?php
// You need to display some friend data
foreach($friends as $friend) {
  echo $friend;
}
```

Then just do whatever you want with the $friends variable.

Answer (score 0):

Either move the loop containing the `echo` statement to another part of the page, or store the results in an array and `echo` them later.